# A better way than `tee | cut | ... | paste`

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing, pipe

Trying to do a "lookup" in a pipeline, where the input looks like this:

```
alice  5
bob    7
...
```

I want to look up codes in the second column in a database and return the corresponding name, and keep on trucking with the original and looked-up data.

```
cat source.tab | \
  tee foo.tmp | \
  cut -f 2 | \
  dbstream ... -s "select(select name from my_lookup where code=?)" | \
  paste foo.tmp -
```

Result should be:

```
alice  5  foo
bob    7  bar
...
```

Imagine for a minute that `cat source.tab` is really a long pipeline that does other pre-processing. And that `dbstream ..` could be some other command, say `wget | jq`.

Important: I only want to start the lookup process once.

a) is this a terrible idea, and if so what should I be doing instead?
b) is there a better pattern than `tee tmp | cut | "lookup" | paste tmp -` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends on how complicated the output is and how much formatting needs to be maintained (eg is the first column always 8 characters long? etc).  However a `while` loop might work

```
cat source.tab | while read -r name id
do
  echo "$name $id $(dbstream .... code=$id)"
done
```

You can change what happens inside the loop to format however you like
eg

```
cat source.tab | while read -r name id
do
  res=$(dbstream ... code=$id)
  printf "%10s %5d %s" $name $id $res
done
```

As per comment, you only want to call `dbstream` once.  This requires `dbstream` to keep output in the same order as input.

Here's a simple example `dbstream` program:

```
#!/bin/sh
for a in "$@"
do
  echo dbstream $$ sees $a
done
```

We include the PID in the output so we can show it only gets called once.

Now we can use `paste` and process substitution:

```
$ paste source.tab <(./dbstream $(awk '{print $2}' source.tab ))
alice 1 dbstream 20671 sees 1
bob   2 dbstream 20671 sees 2
```

Now if the `source.tab` is a slow process I would recommend using a temporary file

eg

```
#!/bin/bash

tmp=`mktemp`

trap '/bin/rm -f $tmp ; exit' 0 1 2 3 15

cat source.tab > $tmp
paste $tmp <(./dbstream $(awk '{print $2}' $tmp ))
```

Comment: does that start a new dbstream process per line? I want to avoid that. thx

Comment: It does.  I'll write a variation that will only call it once.

Comment: nice one. i'll try it at home this eve. cheers

Comment: changed it to `paste source.tab <( awk '{print $2}' source.tab | dbstream )` as dbstream reads from stdin. works!

Comment: Yeah, the exact syntax will depend on the properties of `dbstream`.  In your case using it as a filter does what you want.  The key is the `paste` and process subsitution, along with a temporary file if the source is a one-time data generator (or slow) because the source is processed twice; once for `awk` and once for `paste`.

Comment: and in fact you can say `while IFS= read ...; do ... done < file` instead of `cat file | while ...`.

Comment: @fedorqi if you're going to be pedantic, you should re-read the question

Answer (score 0):

The correct way appears to be to use a named pipe

Example:

```
function datastreamWrapper() {

  mypipe=$(mktemp -u)
  mkfifo -m 600 "$mypipe"

  tee >( cut -f2 | datastream ... > "$mypipe") | paste - "$mypipe"

  rm "$mypipe"
}
```

Then you can put datastreamWrapper in your pipeline:

```
cat source.tab | datastreamWrapper | foo
```